# Exoplayer's renderer's decoder does not adhere to the selected track's format

Tags: android, streaming, exoplayer

I'm testing a HLS source that has four formats: 720p, 360p, 180p, and Audio Only.

My current implementation of Exoplayer is as follows:

```
DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter;

//In onViewCreated()
bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder()
                        .setInitialBitrateEstimate(2000000)
                        .setEventListener(getHandler(), (elapsedMs, bytes, bitrate) -> {
                            try {
                                Trace.i("GameSourceSpecs : " + elapsedMs + " " + bytes + " " + bitrate);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Trace.w(e);
                            }
                        })
                        .build();

private MediaSource buildHLSMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DefaultDataSourceFactory dsf = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getActivity(), "ua", bandwidthMeter);
    DefaultHlsDataSourceFactory dsfHls = new DefaultHlsDataSourceFactory(dsf);
    return new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dsfHls).createMediaSource(uri);
}

TrackSelection.Factory adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory);
((DefaultTrackSelector) trackSelector).setParameters(new DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder().build());

mMediaSource360 = buildHLSMediaSource(Uri.parse("http://35.187.250.251:8880/live/playlist.m3u8"));
mMediaSource360.addEventListener(getHandler(), new MSourceDebuggerListener("GameMediaSource360"));

//noinspection deprecation
mPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(mActivity, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl(
        new DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE),
        1000,  // min buffer
        2000, // max buffer
        1000, // playback
        1000,   //playback after rebuffer
        DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_TARGET_BUFFER_BYTES,
        true
));

mPlayer.prepare(source, true, true);
mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

The HLS file I've been trying to play is as follows:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=544100,RESOLUTION=360x640
chunklist_w2108226616_b544100_sleng.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=294100,RESOLUTION=180x320
chunklist_w2108226616_b294100_sleng.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=48000
chunklist_w2108226616_b48000_ao_sleng.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1044100,RESOLUTION=720x1280
chunklist_w2108226616_b1044100_sleng.m3u8
```

I could see the available tracks in Exoplayer with the `getCurrentMappedTrackInfo()`, listing all the available video tracks resolutions. However, when I tried to set my max video size to 720p using:

`dts.setParameters(new DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder()
                            .setMaxVideoSize(720, 1280)
                            .setMaxVideoBitrate(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                            .build());`

The video track was certainly changed to the 720p one, but the decoder stays 360p. What do I do to make the decoder match the selected track format?

EDIT:

I know the 720p's bitrate is 1044100, and last time I checked when the stream was still on, my bandwidth estimate was well above that (1900000-something).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'The video track was certainly changed to the 720p one, but the decoder stays 360p' - i.e. how you see the track and the decoder values being used?

Comment: I used something extended from `AnalyticsListenerImpl` and logged the `onTracksChanged()` and `onDecoderInputFormatChanged()` callbacks. I could confirm that the video track was indeed changed into the 720p one from the `onTracksChanged()` log, but the decoder stays 360p as indicated in the `onDecoderInputFormatChanged()` log.

Answer (score 0):

It's a false alarm, I'm sorry. As it turned out, said 720p stream was indeed a mislabeled 360p stream, which caused my confusion.

The whole thing was working as intended.